# What newer mathematics fields helped to solve or solved problems from older fields of mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I usually have a more or less formed template of conversation to talk with people about mathematics, It's importance, methods, history, etc. I've been for some time interested in newer fields of mathematics that helped to solve or solved older problems of mathematics but my level of mathematical culture is still too low and I probably don't have good examples in mind.

Although the question may seem an enthusiastic atempt to spread the word of how mathematics is to the laymen, I'm also interested in examples that aren't so accessible for two reasons:

1. I'm curious and perhaps I won't understand now but I have the future to get them.
2. It could be useful/interesting for other members of the community that are way more advanced than the laymen.

Answer (score 21):

1. Fermat's Last Theorem exemplifying how the theory of elliptic curves solves a classical problem in number theory.
2. The proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra using homotopy theory, showing how homotopy theory solves a problem in analysis.
3. Robinson's formalism of nonstandard analysis, showing how logic settles a long standing debate about the existence of infinitesimals.
4. Kolmogorov's axiomatization of probability theory, showing how measure theory is used to give a sound foundation for probability theory.
5. Numerous results in group theory that are proved using Shelah's classification theory, showing how logic solves problems in algebra.
6. Shannon's notion of entropy that created the whole field of information theory, shattering common beliefs in coding theory (e.g., Shannon's theorem on channel capacity).

I'm sure the list continues....

Comment: Another problem was Seven Bridges of Königsberg was solved by Euler who invented graph theory to do so. This is still a 100-200 year gap

Comment: + The proof of the upper bound conjecture using commutative algebra by Richard Stanley.

Comment: @Alizter You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @some1.new4u You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific about 5)? What is Shelah's classification theory and what specific results in group theory can be proven with it?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm really not qualified to explain what Shelah's classification theory is all about. I can't recall now specific problems in group theory solved by Shelah, but there is a long list of such problems in Chang and Keisler's "Model Theory".

Answer (score 13):

Probably the most famous (recent) example is the theory of elliptic curves which was used by Andrew Wiles to prove Fermat's Last Theorem, a conjecture about a particular class of diophantine equations. The problem was famously scrawled in the margin of Fermat's copy of Diophantus' *Arithmetica* with a claim that Fermat had found a proof. However, Fermat's claimed proof was never found and it took over $350$ years to find one using machinery that had not been invented at the time.

There is a lot to this story; I recommend the [BBC documentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FnXgprKgSE) if you would like to know more

Answer (score 10):

**Galois theory**

1. proves the impossibility of classical construction problems with compass and straightedge. (squaring the circle, doubling the cube, angle trisection). Moreover it gives an exact criterion for the constructibility of regular polygons.
2. characterizes the solvability of polynomial equations with radicals.

Comment: 'Newer' in the sense that it's not _quite_ two hundred years old yet? :-)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Note that in the question statement it is 'newer' vs. 'older'. While Galois theory might not be the most recent branch of mathmematics, I guess I'm still right in saying that it is much 'newer' than the older classical construction problems and the question for the solvability of polynomial equations.

Answer (score 1):

Distribution theory, invented about 1950, is now extremely important in the modern theory of linear partial differential equations, e.g. the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem or regularity theorems for elliptic PDO's